# Alternative Functions from Bluetooth Input

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Is it possible to modify what a Bluetooth input effects, such as changing a key press of a Bluetooth keyboard to instead record a tap on a certain location of the screen on your device? (I am running a Kindle Fire HD.)